# Would it make sense to use directive instead of filter to speed up performance?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

It seems like angularjs 1.x filter is not recommended, with the reason given below:

http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/

Angular runs every single filter twice per $digest cycle once something has changed. This is some pretty heavy lifting. The first run is from the $$watchers detecting any changes, the second run is to see if there are further changes that need updated values.

---

I wonder if it make sense to either:

1. Use bind-once with filter
2. Write custom directive that ensures no additional watch is required?

Comment: I'm the main developer of a large AngularJS application and in the main views we never use any inline filters with `ng-repeat`. We have disconnected all the filtering logic from the digest cycle, which is very good for performance. All the filtering and sorting logic is managed in code, and it's triggered explicitly for example when someone changes something in the filter dashboard. This way the filtering won't run when the digest cycle runs.

Comment: Would you say the same for directive? Say if a directive accept a value, do some logic then set back to the element would it be quite effective as well? (Not to compare with doing all the logic code already on the server of course)

Comment: Is this something that needs to be done only once, or multiple times?

Comment: It is something that needs to be done once only, for example when I display a list of product I need to display a converted price in the current currency. Lets just assume this conversion cannot happen server side ^_^